# Is passing an ObjectContext a good idea

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

If I have two distinct methods - one deletes a user and another deletes the user's address (for argument's sake, let's assume they have to be deleted and cannot be set to inactive). If each method creates a repository of that type in order to delete the record, is it considered good practice to create an ObjectContext in the first method and then pass it to the other? If so, should it be passed by value, or reference? What issues or problems can arise from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a valid approach.  The pattern of sharing one context to act on several repositories to accomplish a specific use case is referred to as the Unit of Work pattern.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

http://joel.net/repository-and-unit-of-work-for-entity-framework-ef4-for-unit-testing

Note that you *must* share a context if you require transactional integrity.  If you used separate contexts, and your second delete failed, you would have no way to roll back the first delete.

Comment: I'd heard of the UofW pattern and even read a little bit about it, but it was never really clear until I read the blogs in the first link. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: As a follow up question, I see that they create the Interface for the unit of work and then have the Context class implement the interface. However, I only have the .edmx file, where the code is generated by a tool. How would I implement the interface in this scenario? Do I need to create a class that inherits from the .edmx class and then implement IUnitOfWork??

Comment: I have never worked with .edmx files (I'm code first all the way) so unfortunately I don't know how to answer your follow-up question.  Suggest you post it as a new question.